# In UK, do you say, or used to say, 'candy' to mean 'boiled sweet'?

Tags: meaning, british-english, food

In UK, do you say, or used to say, 'candy' to mean 'boiled sweet'(Br) = 'hard candy'(Am)?

I found this definition on some dictionaries, but except Pocket Oxford, they're all British and rather old (up to 1974), but I can't find it on modern dictionaries.

Dictionaries with "candy" as "boiled sweet":
[1911 Century Dictionary online](http://triggs.djvu.org/century-dictionary.com/djvu2jpg.php?query=candy&djvuurl=http://triggs.djvu.org/century-dictionary.com/01/INDEX.djvu&hittype=&volno=01&page=789&zoom=&format=&label=Volume%201&fromallhits=); The concise Oxford dictionary, 1964; Collins modern English dictionary, 1974; The pocket Oxford dictionary, 1992.

EDIT: below is added after the comments by @Unrelated, @Clare and the answer by @Laurel.

This definition is also given in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/candy), which is American. (OTOH MW says "[sweet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sweet)" can mean "hard candy" in UK, which I've never seen anywhere else.)

Dictionaries (and other usages) *without* this definition:

- [Oxford learner's dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/candy), [Longman dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/candy), [Collins cobuild](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/candy), [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/candy), [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/candy)

  - They all have the entry "boiled sweet".
- Neither these online dictionaries (not so much trustworthy, I think): [dictonary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/candy), [the free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/candy)
- Wikipedia' page [candy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candy) does not say the bare word "candy" means "hard candy", though it does not prove anything.

  - But in [its talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Candy#Semi-protected_edit_request_on_18_October_2016), a user says that Br "candy" means "rock candy" in N.Am.
- The [search result](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/?url=search-alias%3Dgrocery&field-keywords=candy) at amazon.co.uk for the word "candy" shows sweets/candies in general.

Comment: Before people come pouncing on you, you might want to add the text from the dictionaries

Comment: What online dictionaries did you try? As the answer by @Laurel shows  the ODO (Oxford Online Dictionary) definition 1.1 gives the definition you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what dictionary you're using, but mine has this entry for "candy":

> *British* Sugar crystallized by repeated boiling and slow evaporation.
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/candy)</sub>

The blog [Separated by a Common Language](https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2006/07/candy-and-sweets.html) gives a great explanation:

> In BrE, candy refers to things that are made from sugar that's been melted (usually with water and some flavo(u)ring) and resolidified in some form, including boiled sweets (AmE = hard candy) and candy floss (AmE = cotton candy).

Comment: Thanks. For the record, (1) in that blog post, there's also a comment "The Australian definition of candy is more or less the same as the one you give for British." (2) That blog's subtitle is "Observation on British [...] English by an American linguist in the UK."

Comment: It's a tricky issue, because as a Briton if I heard the word "candy" I'd assume someone was using an Americanism, not talking about hard candy or another specific category of speech. Although the word formerly had other meanings/connotations in the UK, American candy is now fairly widely available in Britain, and the American usage is more widely known.

Answer (score 3):

So I'll fess up and candidly admit, I used to live in the UK and never once did I utter  the word *candy* to talk about sweets, but that was a hundred years ago and since then it's possible that British children have become  more familiar with the term *candy*, meaning sweets, in all its myriad of forms.

Today, I don't know if Brits  say *candy* or *hard candy* in place of *hard-boiled sweets*, but they definitely say **candy floss** (the sickly sticky pinky fluff on a stick). And instead of calling it [Brighton rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_(confectionery)), they might say ***candy cane***; the stripy stick made from granulated sugar, shaped like a walking stick (a cane), but the place where Brits buy their sugary snacks is called a *sweet shop*, although *candy store* seems to be close behind (which is odd!). If you can't find a sweet shop, pop into a newsagent's, they'll have a rack of sweets and chocolates opposite the cash till or right beside the counter.

[image]

If we swim across the pond, it is the *candy store* which is most used by American English speakers, according to Google Ngram that is.

[image]

Finally, Wikipedia seems to confirm my earlier suspicion that *boiled sweets* are not synonymous with *hard candy*. They list it under
*[Glossary of British terms not widely used in the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_British_terms_not_widely_used_in_the_United_States#B)*

> ***boiled sweet*** type of confection (US: hard candy)

And Longman Dictionary says **[boiled sweet](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/boiled-sweet)** is British English.

The sticky *toffee apple* of my childhood is, I discover, commonly referred to as *candy apple* or *caramel apple* (also pronounced as [/ˈkɑrml/](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/caramel))  in the US.

[image]

See also the enjoyable YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5OrW9YOK-4): **15 British Sweets Everyone Should Try** - Anglophenia Ep 22

Comment: I know this is an old one (and it's a generally good answer), but I just want to comment on the NGrams - I've found that NGrams is unreliable at distinguishing between British and American English.  A lot of American books are republished in the UK and these seem to get filed under English (British) in NGrams.  In real life, "candy store" is still very rare in British usage (I lived in the UK until last year).